# How to monitor and log my internet connectivity on Mojave

Tags: macos, network, mojave, software-recommendation, internet

I need to run a program remotely and need to keep my iMac (Mojave) connected to internet for hours. It seems when I leave my iMac, my program will stop running. I suspect that is due to some internet connectivity issue. I have my iMac so that it never goes to sleep when my display does in the power saver.

[Edited: Added] I need to know about internet reachability with a timestamp and Not the time when my program exits!

Are there software or scripts I could run periodically to make a log of this?

Comment: Are you simply looking to know when one program starts and stops? That could be far simpler than guessing if the network is connected. I’ve edited this on the assumption that you really need to know about internet reachability and not just when a program exits. Please edit again if I missed the actual problem you need solved.

Answer (score 1):

Apple’s Wireless Diagnostics tool might work. It appears to be able to monitor your connectivity and provide a report based on the results. You can find it in spotlight search.

[image: wireless Diagnostics]